# Is it acceptable to do Wudu in the bathroom? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, wudu, taharah, najis

Toilet space (room) is considered as a dirty place and ordinarily this is a place for nejasah (impurities) (and its space can be polluted due to urine/feces...), on the other hand, making Wudu is counted as a clean (Taharah) practice.  I was wondering if it is permissible to make our Wudu (Wudhu) into the space of toilet? (I mean: not to make Wudhu in the toilet (which is a large bowl connected to the drains which..., but I mean in the room of the toilet, and in the sink (washbasin).

**Notice:** I don't mean in the bathroom, because in some homes the bathroom is apart from toilet room.

*Note: I'm looking for the viewpoint of Shia*.

Answer (score 2):

Performing Wudhu in the space of toilet is not deemed as a haram (forbidden) practice and as a result it is a permissible practice. Solely, it would be Makruh *(Makruh means it is better not to do, but is it not haram)* if the water of Wudhu spills into the sewer of the toilet. (It might be related to this issue that the water of Wudhu is deemed as a Taaher water, then it can be considered as a sort of disrespect …)

*WaAllahu-A’lamo*

---

**Reference:**

- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/12146/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B4%D9%88%DB%8C%DB%8C)

Comment: No, I mean the water from the sink (washbasin) which is available in a part of the toilet and you can wash your hands and faces , otherwise I presume direct water of toilet is najis (unclean)..., I appreciate you for mentioning this important issue. God bless you.